# Most concise way to make list items from each line break

Tags: lists, shorthands

How can I convert every line to a list item automatically?

for example I want following become a list (without adding more characters):

```
\begin{foo}
Persian
French 
Arabic
Urdu
\end{foo}
```

- Persian
- French
- Arabic
- Urdu

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the input is exactly laid out as you show, with `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}` on lines by themselves, the following will do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checkForEnd}{\@ifnextchar\end{}{\item}}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{foo}
 {\par\obeylines
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\checkForEnd
  \begin{itemize}}
 {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
Persian
French
Arabic
Urdu
\end{foo}

\begin{itemize}
\item Persian
\item French
\item Arabic
\item Urdu
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The result of the two environments will be the same. But the `foo` environment should not appear in the *argument* to a command.

You can of course modify the appearance of the `itemize` environment, with the help of the package `enumitem`. For instance

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{foo}
 {\par\obeylines
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\checkForEnd
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]}
 {\end{itemize}}
```

will "kill" all vertical space, while `noitemsep` in place of `nosep` will remove the space between the items, leaving the separation of the environment from the text above and below it.

You can even do the setup for each `foo` environment with

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{foo}[1][]
 {\par\obeylines
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\checkForEnd
  \begin{itemize}[#1]}
 {\end{itemize}}
```

so that the options can be passed as optional argument to `foo`; for instance,

```
\begin{foo}[nosep]
Persian
French
Arabic
Urdu
\end{foo}
```

Comment: @Reza It builds a *real* itemize environment.

Comment: After a year your code save the day again. thanks

Answer (score 12):

Here is one option: Using `\obeylines` and an "`itemize` definition" for `\everypar`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{foo}
  {\obeylines\everypar{\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep}}}% \begin{foo}
  {}% \end{foo}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
Persian
French 
Arabic
Urdu
\end{foo}

\begin{itemize}
\item Persian
\item French 
\item Arabic
\item Urdu
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```