# \newcommand with optional multi-line argument and implicit itemize environment

Tags: macros, lists, itemize, optional-arguments

While drafting a text, I want to subdivide and group text pieces and keywords to easily reorder them throughout the document.

Examples for such a group of text pieces would be:

---

*Example 1): Two arguments (2nd is optional and multi-line)*

Having in the LaTeX file something like...

```
\mycommand{Summary of this paragraph (always provided)} {
    optional textline 1
    optional textline 2
    ...
}
```

...should result in the pdf as...

> **Summary of this paragraph (always provided)**
>
> - optional textline 1
> - optional textline 2
> - ...

---

*Example 2): One argument*

Having in the LaTeX file something like...

```
\mycommand{Summary of this paragraph (always provided)}
```

...should result (without optional arguments) in the pdf as...

> **Summary of this paragraph (always provided)**

---

I tried already some things with `\newcommand` but I'm not a real expert.

The needed features would be

- `\mycommand` gets at least one argument and prints this to the PDF (e.g. in **bold letters**)
- `\mycommand` takes a variable number of following lines (in parenthesis) as second argument and adds for each new line an `\item` to an `\itemize` list (without writing the `\item` in the `.tex`-file)
- Changing the `\mycommand` to display only text would then finally generate a running text without the need of removing the `\item` commands.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) allows to use so-called “Inline lists”. You still need the `\item`s but you can switch from “Normal” to “Inline” very easily without re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can profit of `xparse` and LaTeX3 functions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\outline}{ m o }
 {
  \par\noindent\textbf{#1}
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {
    \par\vspace{\topsep} % no list of items
   }
   {
    \egreg_outline_items:n { #2 } % there are items
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_egreg_outline_items_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_outline_items:n #1
 {
  % split the \\ separated list of items
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_egreg_outline_items_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % make an itemize with them
  \begin{itemize}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_egreg_outline_items_seq
   {
    \item ##1
   }
  \end{itemize}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\outline{Some text for the outline}

Here is something in the section.

\section{Second}

\outline{Here I have more}[
  something \\
  something else \\
  again
]

Here is something in the section.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about combining this with elements from [Most concise way to make list items from each line break](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73604/5764) to auto `\item`-ize elements based on line breaks?

Comment: @Werner That's different, because there the items are supposed to be short and here they might span more than one line.

Comment: @Werner That would in fact be the point: The answer from egreg still requires the \\ at the end of each sentence. When generating a final version of the document (running text) the \\ would force a new line for each sentence.

Comment: @user258346 In a final version you can change the definition of `\egreg_outline_items:n` to do what you want with the various ``\\``-separated items. That's the advantage of marking up the document; an end of line instead of ``\\`` wouldn't be as good, because editor programs sometimes have strange ideas about what to do with long lines. Exchanging the document with a coworker or your supervisor could break the line divisions.

Comment: I run into problems when trying to make it run with pdflatex on ubuntu 12.04. Including \usepackage{expl3} did not help: 
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    \egreg_outline_items:n
    #1->\seq_set_split:Nnn                                          \l_egreg_outline_items_seq {\\...
l.45 ]

Comment: @user258346 You have an outdated TeX Live, probably 2009.