# Need a Macro for Tables - independent of row and column size

Tags: tables, macros, environments

I have created the following macro for Table:

```
\newcommand{\createtable}[7]{
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}||p{8cm}|}
\hline
\begin{center}\textbf{\cellcolor{Orchid!25}{#1}}\end{center} &
\begin{center}\textbf{\cellcolor{Orchid!25}{#2}}\end{center} \\
\hline\hline
 {#3} 
 & {#4}\\
 \hline
 {#5}
 & {#6}\\ 
\hline
    \end{tabular}%
 \centering
 \caption{#7}
\end{table}
}
```

Usage:

```
\createtable
    {Label1} 
    {Label2}
    {Text1-1}
    {Text2-1}
    {Text1-2}
    {Text2-2}
    {Table Title}
```

Output:

[image]

Problem:

Reference:
[\newcommand with optional multi-line argument and implicit itemize environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136122/newcommand-with-optional-multi-line-argument-and-implicit-itemize-environment)

Here, we can create a dynamic bullet list, without any prior knowledge of the number of items.

I need a similar macro for tables, so that if I write:

```
\createtable
  {Label1}
  {Label2}
  {Label3}
  {Text1-Label1
   \&
   Text1-Label2
   \&
   Text1-Label3
   \\
   Text2-Label1
   \&
   Text2-Label2
   \& 
   Text2-Label3
}
```

The macro should be intelligent enough to figure out that:

```
[1] Table has 3 columns -- Label1, Label2 and Label3
[2] Distribute the text-input separated by \& among these columns, i.e. 
   Text1-Label1 under Label1, Text1-Label2 under Label2 and Text1-Label3 under Label3

[3] Identify the end of row marker as "//"
    and add further entries (using the procedure described in 
    point [2]) to the next row.
```

Can anyone please provide some pointers.

This is what I tried initially:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\testtable}{ m o }
{
  % split the \\ separated list of items
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_egreg_outline_items_seq { \\ } { #1 }
\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}||p{8cm}|}
\hline
\begin{center}\textbf{\cellcolor{Orchid!25}{Column1}}\end{center} &
\begin{center}\textbf{\cellcolor{Orchid!25}{Column2}}\end{center} \\
\hline\hline
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_egreg_outline_items_seq
   {
    ##1 %\hline
   }
    \end{tabular}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If we can't provide number of columns at run-time, that is ok, but number of rows should be added dynamically.

Comment: The `solution` is somehow *indicated* in the linked question: Use `\NewDocumentCommand` and lists.

Comment: Yes, but that is more 'horizontally' oriented, I am running into problems because of columns

Comment: You are asking for a lot of cleverness, but how much? Will this macro sometimes create two-column tables and other times five-column tables? Also: why can't the macro specify explicitly how many columns there will be?  Fiinally, I can't help but wonder if a `.csv`-driven approach (using either `datatool` or `csvsimple`) wouldn't be a way easier method to do what you want.  These macros will probably be extremely brittle....

Comment: ok, if we keep number of columns as predefined, can we keep number of rows variable?  I have added my initial code and updated question about fix columns

Comment: Where's the data for the table coming from? Is it generated from another source?

Comment: No, I am just writing a simplified new command which is easy to use (re-use to be more specific)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest the usage of `\createtable` as follows:

```
\createtable 3 {3cm}
  {Label1}        {Label2}       {Label3}
  {Text1-Label1 | Text1-Label2 | Text1-Label3 |
   Text2-Label1 | Text2-Label2 | Text2-Label3 }
  {Table title}
```

You can see that you must specify the number of columns (3 in the example) and the width of columns (3cm in the example). You are using a fixed column width in your example, so there is a good reason to specify it.

The implementation should be:

```
\newcount\tmpnum   
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\createtable#1#2{\def\tabcols{#1}\def\colwidth{#2}%
   \def\tabdata{}\def\tabdataA{}\tmpnum=0 \createtableA}
\def\createtableA#1{\advance\tmpnum by1
   \addto\tabdata{\begin{center}\textbf{\cellcolor{red!25}{#1}}\end{center}}%
   \addto\tabdataA{|p{\colwidth}|}%
   \ifnum\tabcols>\tmpnum
      \addto\tabdata{&}\expandafter\createtableA
   \else
      \addto\tabdata{\\ \hline\hline}\expandafter\createtableB
   \fi
}
\def\createtableB#1{\tmpnum=0 \createtableC#1||}
\def\createtableC#1|{\ifx|#1|\expandafter\createtableD\else   
   \advance\tmpnum by1
   \ifnum\tabcols=\tmpnum \addto\tabdata{{#1}\\ \hline}\tmpnum=0
   \else \addto\tabdata{{#1}&}%
   \fi
   \expandafter\createtableC \fi
}
\def\createtableD#1{%
   \begin{table}[htbp]
   \edef\tmp{\noexpand\begin{tabular}{\tabdataA}}\tmp
   \hline
   \tabdata
   \end{tabular}
   \centering\caption{#1}
   \end{table}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you input the labels in a unique argument, it's easy to figure out the number of columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createtable}{mm}
 {
  \sandeep_ct_create_table:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_sandeep_ct_cols_int
\seq_new:N \l_sandeep_ct_head_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_sandeep_ct_head_output_seq
\seq_new:N \l_sandeep_ct_table_body_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sandeep_ct_create_table:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_sandeep_ct_head_input_seq { & } { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_sandeep_ct_cols_int
   {
    \seq_count:N \l_sandeep_ct_head_input_seq
   }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_sandeep_ct_head_output_seq \l_sandeep_ct_head_input_seq
   {
    \exp_not:n { \multicolumn{1}{c}{\ctbigstrut\bfseries ##1} }
   }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_sandeep_ct_table_body_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{*{\l_sandeep_ct_cols_int}{X}}
  \toprule
  \addlinespace[0pt]
  \rowcolor{orchid}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_sandeep_ct_head_output_seq { & } \\
  \addlinespace[0pt]
  \midrule
  \seq_use:Nn \l_sandeep_ct_table_body_seq { \\ \addlinespace }
  \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\ctbigstrut}{%
  \vrule height .8cm
         depth \dimexpr.8cm-\ht\strutbox\relax
         width 0pt
}

\definecolor{orchid}{RGB}{242,213,230}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\createtable
 {
  Label 1 & Label 2
 }
 {
  Text1-Label1
  &
  Text1-Label2
  \\
  Text2-Label1
  &
  Text2-Label2
}   

\bigskip

\noindent
\createtable
 {
  Label 1 & Label 2 & Label 3
 }
 {
  Text1-Label1
  &
  Text1-Label2
  &
  Text1-Label3
  \\
  Text2-Label1
  &
  Text2-Label2
  & 
  Text2-Label3
 }

\end{document}
```

The first argument is split at `&` to count the number of columns; the items are then put as the argument of `\multicolumn`.

Then we split the table body at `\\` in order to be able to add `\addlinespace` between rows.

[image]